# how to add a horizontal line between top text and bottom date in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

how to add a horizontal line between top text and bottom date in MS word like below. actually, I could not add horizontal line also in the below sample.

```
     2048
  3/10/2023
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a question about code?

Is this what you want below? Thus press -, =, _, * three times, and then press Enter key you'll get it. If this is what just you want, then next time remember to ask on the [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) site, not here. Thanks.

[image]

### use Character Symbols to achieve

```vb
Sub CharacterSymbols_how_to_add_a_horizontal_line_between_top_text_and_bottom_date_in_MS_Word()
    
    Dim line As String, charCount As Byte, i As Byte, a As Range, ur As UndoRecord
    
    If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then
        MsgBox "Plz Select the range you want to...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If Selection.Paragraphs.Count <> 2 Then
            MsgBox "Only 2 paragraphs can be selected, Plz", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "CharacterSymbols_how_to_add_a_horizontal_line_between_top_text_and_bottom_date_in_MS_Word"
    
    Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With Selection
        charCount = VBA.IIf(.Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters.Count > .Paragraphs(2).Range.Characters.Count, .Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters.Count, .Paragraphs(2).Range.Characters.Count)
        
        Rem The length of the line: This applies to narrow-form characters such as English letters and numbers, but not to wide-form characters such as Chinese characters. No need to divide by 2 if the character is in wide one.
        'charCount = charCount / 2 - 1
        charCount = VBA.IIf(FullOrHalf(.Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters(1)) = 1, charCount / 2 - 1, charCount) ' temporarily according to the first character
        For i = 1 To charCount
            line = line + "─"
        Next
        Set a = .Paragraphs(2).Range.Characters(1)
        a.InsertBefore Chr(13)
        .SetRange a.Start, a.Start
        .TypeText line
        With .Paragraphs(1).Range.ParagraphFormat
            .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceExactly
            .LineSpacing = VBA.Int(a.Font.Size / 2)
            .BaseLineAlignment = wdBaselineAlignCenter
        End With
        While .Paragraphs(1).Next.Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber) - .Paragraphs(1).Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber) > 1
            .Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters(1).Text = VBA.vbNullString
        Wend
    End With
    
    ur.EndCustomRecord
    Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Rem https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/600306305
Public Function FullOrHalf(ByVal str As String) As Integer
    Dim strLocal As String
    Debug.Assert Len(str) = 1
    If Len(str) <> 1 Then
        FullOrHalf = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    strLocal = StrConv(str, vbFromUnicode)
    If Len(str) * 2 = LenB(strLocal) Then
        FullOrHalf = 2 ' wide
    ElseIf Len(str) = LenB(strLocal) Then
        FullOrHalf = 1 ' narrow
    Else
        FullOrHalf = 0 ' error
    End If
End Function
```

- Before

[image]

- After

[image]

Comment: thanks, I wanted horizontal line to be fit the size of words i write not fit to the page. because there are words behind and front of horizontal line.

Comment: @Masoud So, do you want the line to be made up of shapes, table lines, or character symbols? I've used character symbols to achieve first as an example. Maybe you can try first.

Comment: @Masoud I've already updated my code a few days ago. Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks, Now for example I have to type "2048" and then press "Enter" and Then Run the "VBA" Code" and then "3/10/2023"?

Comment: @Masoud Reading my code you should know it is according your selecting range.`MsgBox "Only 2 paragraphs can be selected, Plz", vbCritical` So you should typed all your text( the up is number `2048` and then key Enter, and then bottom is date `3/10/2023`. ps. the data type just text string is ok, unnecessary to be number and date.) then select the top to bottom range ( all of them are just two paragraphs in the active document), then run the code to check it out.